# Google fonts displaying outside pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, google-fonts, html5-template

We are fetching Text [ Text1 & Text2 ] from JSON & display in page , Once user click on Text, we are displaying pop up box....

**Requirement** :

I want to display all google fonts inside pop up box in dropdown....

**Issue** :

Google Fonts are displaying outside the Pop up box instead of inside....

**Logic** :

Whatever code i write inside template tag should display inside pop up box.... but here its displaying outside....

[image]

```
    <template id='template2'>
    <input type="range" min="40" max="80" oninput="fontRange(this)"
    <script>

    $(function() {
        $('#font').fontselect().change(function() {

            // replace + signs with spaces for css
            var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

            // split font into family and weight
            font = font.split(':');

            // set family on paragraphs 
            $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
        });
    });

    </script>
    </template>
```

**script**

```
$('.container').append(
            '<div id="font"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a></div>  ' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
            $('#template2').html() + 
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/NmyPKN

Below is code snippet :

```js
//font color
var className;

function changeColor(data) {
    var color = $(data).css('background-color');
    var changeColor = $(className).css('color', color);
}

//font color end


// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
 
 //font color

    var colorID = el.id.substring(5);
    className = '#' + colorID;

    //font color end
 
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}

function fontRange(e) {
  var element = e.parentElement.id;
  element = "#edit_" + element.split("_")[1];
  $(element).css('font-size', e.value + 'px');
}

let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
   "layers":[  
      {  
         "x":0,
         "height":612,
         "layers":[  
            {  
               "x":160,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":36,
                     "y":63,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
                     "type":"text",
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"Text1",
                     "name":"edit_mayer"
                  }
               ],
               "y":291,
               "name":"user_image_1"
            },
            {  
               "x":25,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":136,
                     "y":163,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "type":"text",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"Text2",
                     "name":"edit_sale"
                  }
               ],
               "y":22,
               "name":"L2"
            }
         ],
         "y":0,
         "width":612,
         "name":"L1"
      }
   ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   
    // Below code will fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                    
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

// Text code

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<input id="font" style="display:none"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>  ' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
   $('#template2').html() + 
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
      

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };       
     };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}

.radiobutton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radiobutton span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.radiobutton span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .radiobutton span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.red .radiobutton span {
  background: #FFC107;
}

.radiocolor {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css" />
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container"></div>

<template id='template2'>
<input type="range" min="10" max="40" oninput="fontRange(this)" onchange="fontRange(this)"> 

<label class="orange">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" style="display:none" >
      <div class="radiocolor"></div>
      <div class="radiobutton"><span onclick="changeColor(this)"></span></div>
   </label>
   <label class="red">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" style="display:none" >
      <div class="radiocolor"></div>
      <div class="radiobutton"><span onclick="changeColor(this)"></span></div>
   </label>

<script>

$(function() {
    $('#font').fontselect().change(function() {

        // replace + signs with spaces for css
        var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

        // split font into family and weight
        font = font.split(':');

        // set family on paragraphs 
        $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
    });
});
    
</script>
</template>
```

Comment: please give me reason for downvote, so that  i will correct it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this codepen i done for you https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLmpeL

where i added global class called `className` and add id of that in className.

now i get style value of popup and add into dropdown and add some px for look nice

```
var styleTop = el.style.top;
var styleLeft = el.style.left;

styleTop = parseInt(styleTop.substring(3 , -1)) + 130;
styleLeft = parseInt(styleLeft.substring(3 , -1)) + 30;

console.log(styleTop);
console.log(styleLeft);

$('.font-select:first').css({
    display: 'block',
    left: styleLeft + 'px',
    top: styleTop + 'px',
    zIndex: 1010
});
```

Hope you like it.